# Why accordion is not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery accordion control.It's working in IE9 but not working in IE8 browser.please tell me solution for this to resolve that ie8 accordion issue.
I am trying for that from long time.please give me answer...

Comment: jQuery UI (including the Accordion widget) supports IE 8; more information is needed to diagnose "not working".

Comment: Do u mean Jquery UI accordion? else point to the link for the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI Accordion supports IE8,

**jquery;**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/NG4Y9/)

Check [UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)